# What kinds of functions have fixed points?

Tags: polynomials, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

Among continuous functions, can we characterize those which have fixed points and those which do not?

Geometrically, these are the functions that intersect the line $f(x) = x$. Is that the most concise description we can give?

For instance, all polynomials of degree $0$ (constant functions $f(x) = c$) have fixed points, not all polynomials of degree $1$ or $2$ do, but all cubic functions do (since they start with one sign and end with the other, they must cross the line). In general all odd-degree polynomials have at least one fixed point.

But some quadratics (e.g. $f(x) = x^2 - 1$) have fixed points, while others ($x^2 + 1$) do not. What's the difference?

Comment: $f(x)-x$ has a root? (I know, it's just a restatement of intersecting $f(x)-x$, but there's no way to simplify the condition that $f(x)-x$ has a root.)

Comment: Nitpicks: Not all cubics start positive and end negative. Also, not all odd-degree polynomials have at least one fixed point, because a polynomial of degree 1 is an odd-degree polynomial. Anyway, I don't think anything more can be said beyond Mihir's comment.

Comment: Over $\mathbb C$, all polynomials not of the form $x+c$ have a fixed point.

Comment: "all odd-degree polynomials", but $x+c$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a truly general result, but one result is that every contraction map from a complete metric space $(X,d)$ to itself, i.e., a map $f$ so that $d(x,y)>d(f(x),f(y))$ has a (unique) fixed point, and there is a formula for it.

There are many other fixed-point results, like Brouwer's fixed point theorem that says that every continuous map from the closed unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ to itself must have a fixed point.

There are many other results, including the Banach Fixed Point thm, but no one overarching one that I am familiar with:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_theorem

Comment: I think you mean *Brouwer's* fixed point theorem, not "Brewer's"?

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, let me edit. I was thinking of beer, I guess....

Answer (score 1):

Fixed point of a function f(x) are those $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x$.
For the case $f(x)=x^2+1$, the fixed points of $f(x)$ are $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2+1=x$. So arranging this gives $x^2-x+1=0$, with a=1, b=-1 and c=1 when compared with $ax^2+bx+c=0$. Now, $b^2-4ac=1-4=-3$. So $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=\sqrt{-3}$ does not have a solution in the set of real numbers. Thus, $f(x)=x^2+1$ has no fixed point in $\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, $f(x)=x^2-1$ (by a similar computation as above) has fixed points in $\mathbb{R}$ since $\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \geq 0$.