# Common fixed points of two polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

According to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48818/on-common-fixed-points-of-commuting-polynomials-and-rational-functions?rq=1) (Ritt's classification), given two commuting polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[z]$, there exists a common fixed point of them.
By commuting we mean: $f(g(z))=g(f(z))$.

Of course, a polynomial $h(z)$ over $\mathbb{C}$, not of the form $z+\lambda$,
$\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$ has a fixed point, since there is a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ to $h(z)=z$; notice that for this claim $\mathbb{C}$ can be replaced by any algebraically closed field; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358081/what-kinds-of-functions-have-fixed-points).

> Is it possible to replace $\mathbb{C}$ by any algebraically closed field of characteristic zero in the common fixed point result?

Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it holds for any algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Since the statement can be formulated in first-order logic, all you have to do is to apply the [Lefschetz principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry#The_Lefschetz_principle).

Comment: Thank you very much! Sounds what I was looking for. I guess it is also possible to read carefully the proof for $\mathbb{C}$ and check that it is still valid if we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by any algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, but your argument seems better.

Comment: I only mentioned the Lefschetz principle because it was the only method that I was able to think of in order to solve your problem. But I suspect that is I knew the proof for $\mathbb C$, then it should be clear that it would wotk for every algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, I do not have a reference for the proof over $\mathbb{C}$, so the method you suggested really helps. (I guess that proofs over $\mathbb{C}$ should usually still be valid if we replace it by an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, at least when the Lefschetz principle can be applied).